# Proof of an identity in Monte Carlo

Tags: brownian-motion, monte-carlo

In my professors notes we have lemma 14 which states that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} W(t_i)\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2n-(2i-1)t_i\right)$$
where $W(t)$ is the standard Brownian motion. The proof of this uses this identity without proving it $$\sum_{i,j}min(t_i,t_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2n-(2i-1))t_i$$

I want to try to prove this identity but I am confused on where to even start, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you assume without loss of generality that $t_{i}<t_{j}$ if $i<j$?  Can you see how to prove this for $t_{1}<t_{2}<t_{3}$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I am not sure but it seems like a fair assumption to me. It is still unclear to me how to start for the case $t_1 < t_2 < t_3$.

Comment: What Do you know about the distributions of $W(t_{1})$, $W(t_{2})$ and $W(t_{3})$ if $t_{1} < t_{2} < t_{3}$?  What about $W(t_{2})-W(t_{1})$? $W(t_{3})-W(t_{2})$, etc.?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I am not sure about the condition of being $t_1 < t_2 < t_3$. But, $W(t_1),W(t_2)$, and $W(t_2) = W(t_1)$, I believe are $\mathcal{N}(0,t)$?

Comment: $W(t_{1})$ is $N(0,t_{1})$, and $W(t_{2})-W(t_{1})$ is $N(0,t_{2}-t_{1})$ and indepdendent of $W(t_{1})$.    Can you see a way to make use of that?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Been thinking about this but I am still a bit lost, could you post an answer to this question?

Comment: I'm assuming that this is an exercise that you've been asked to do.  That's why I've provided you with hints.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Appreciate it, but no its not an exercise or Homework, just something I thought would be good to know how to prove.

Comment: @BrianBorchers any chance you could post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $t_1 < t_2 < \cdots < t_n$. Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n W(t_i)$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance
\begin{align*}
E\bigg(\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n W(t_i) \Big)^2 \bigg) &= \sum_{i, j=1}^n E\Big(W(t_i)W(t_j) \Big)\\
&= \sum_{i, j=1}^n  \min(t_i, t_j)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n t_i + 2\sum_{i<j}\min(t_i, t_j)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n t_i + 2\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i)t_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\big(2n-2i +1 \big)t_i.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n W(t_i) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \ \sum_{i=1}^n\big(2n-2i +1 \big)t_i\right).
\end{align*}